# How do I set a precision to what a function prints to an output file from an array

Tags: c++, arrays, precision

I need help setting a precision to what gets printed to an output file in my function called Print_DB. I implemented a function called Menu that sets up a main menu, when the user selects to print to an output file, a function called Process makes necessary calculations grabbing values from an array holding cellphone information. I want these calculations to be printed on the output file as such:

```
9546321555  0   0   0.00    0.01    0.00    0.00    yes
5612971340  5   50  2.00    0.01    0.02    2.02    no
3051234567  8   25  1.60    0.03     0.05    1.65   no
7542346622  24  17   3.26   0.08     0.26    3.53   no
3054432762  15  30  3.60    0.05    0.18    3.78    yes
9544321011  50  100 40.00   0.08    3.20    43.20   yes
8776219988  87  82   57.07  0.12     6.85    63.92  yes
9042224556  4   5   0.16    0.01     0.00    0.16   yes
7877176590  11  1    0.09   0.03    0.00     0.09   no
5617278899  20  45  7.20    0.05    0.36     7.56   no
9546321555  4   3    0.10   0.01     0.00    0.10   yes
5612971340  79  86   54.35  0.12     6.52    60.87  no
3051234567  8   25  1.60    0.03     0.05    1.65   no
7542346622  24  118  22.66  0.08     1.81    24.47  no
3054432762  115 25  23.00   0.12    2.76     25.76  yes
9544321011  43  10  3.44    0.08     0.28    3.72   yes
8776219988  265 22  46.64   0.12    5.60     52.24  yes
9042224556  2   5   0.08    0.01     0.00    0.08   yes
7877176590  89  67   47.70  0.12     5.72    53.43  no
5617278899  40  56  17.92   0.08     1.43    19.35  no
```

But instead, i get something like this:

```
9546321555  0   0   -9.25596e+061   -9.25596e+061   8.56729e+121    8.56729e+121    yes
5612971340  5   50  2   0.01    0.0002  2.0002  no
3051234567  8   25  1.6 0.03    0.00048 1.60048 no
7542346622  24  17  3.264   0.08    0.0026112   3.26661 no
3054432762  15  30  1.8 0.05    0.0009  1.8009  yes
9544321011  50  100 40  0.08    0.032   40.032  yes
8776219988  87  82  57.072  0.12    0.0684864   57.1405 yes
9042224556  4   5   0.16    0.01    1.6e-005    0.160016    yes
7877176590  11  1   0.088   0.03    2.64e-005   0.0880264   no
5617278899  20  45  3.2 0.05    0.0016  3.2016  no
9546321555  4   3   0.096   0.01    9.6e-006    0.0960096   yes
5612971340  79  86  54.352  0.12    0.0652224   54.4172 no
3051234567  8   25  1.6 0.03    0.00048 1.60048 no
7542346622  24  118 22.656  0.08    0.0181248   22.6741 no
3054432762  115 25  23  0.12    0.0276  23.0276 yes
9544321011  43  10  3.44    0.08    0.002752    3.44275 yes
8776219988  265 22  46.64   0.12    0.055968    46.696  yes
9042224556  2   5   0.08    0.01    8e-006  0.080008    yes
7877176590  89  67  47.704  0.12    0.0572448   47.7612 no
5617278899  40  56  17.92   0.08    0.014336    17.9343 no
```

I would also like the function "Discount" to print exactly the same. What do i need to add or fix? Help? Hints? thank you!
Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>


//************************************************************************
//Name:  Kevin          Due Date: 022113
//Instructor: Dr. Bullard               Total Points:  100 pts
//Assignment2: client_call.cpp          UsIDFAU: 
//:


using namespace std;

const int CAPACITY = 20;

 class client_db
  {
  public:
    string cellnum;
    int numofrelay;
    int call_length;
    double net_cost;
    double tax_rate;
    double call_tax;
    double total_cost;
    string discount_aval;
   };

bool IsFull(int); //returns true if the array is full; otherwise false.
bool IsEmpty(int count);// returns ture if the array is empty; otherwise false.

void Add(client_db A[], int & count, client_db & db);
void Remove(client_db A[], int *count, string name);// removes an item from the array if it is there
void Print_DB(client_db A[], int count);//prints to output file
void Call_stats(client_db A[], int count);// prints all the items in the array
int Search_DB(client_db A[], int count, string name); //if the name is in the array, its location is returned
//                                        //otherwise return -1;
//
bool IsFull(int count)
////Description: Determines if the array is full
{
    return (count == CAPACITY);
}

bool IsEmpty(int count)
////Description: Determines if the array is empty
{
    return (count == 0);
}

void Process (client_db A[], int count)
{

    for(int i=0; i<count; i++)
    {
    if (A[i].numofrelay >=1 && A[i].numofrelay<=5)
    {
        A[i].tax_rate=0.01;
        A[i].net_cost = ((A[i].numofrelay / 50.0)*0.40*A[i].call_length);

    }
    else if (A[i].numofrelay >=6 && A[i].numofrelay<=11)
    {
        A[i].tax_rate=0.03;
        A[i].net_cost = ((A[i].numofrelay / 50.0)*0.40*A[i].call_length);


    }
    else if (A[i].numofrelay>=12 && A[i].numofrelay<=20)
    { 
        A[i].tax_rate=0.05;
        A[i].net_cost = ((A[i].numofrelay / 50.0)*0.40*A[i].numofrelay);


    }
    else if (A[i].numofrelay >=21 && A[i].numofrelay<=50)
    {
       A[i].tax_rate =0.08;
       A[i].net_cost = ((A[i].numofrelay / 50.0)*0.40*A[i].call_length);


    }
    else if (A[i].numofrelay >50)
    {
        A[i].tax_rate =0.12;
        A[i].net_cost = ((A[i].numofrelay / 50.0)*0.40*A[i].call_length);


    }
    A[i].call_tax = ((A[i].tax_rate)/(100))*(A[i].net_cost);
    A[i].total_cost = A[i].net_cost + A[i].call_tax;
    }
}

void Print_DB(client_db A[], int count)

//Description: Prints the items stored in A to the standard i/o device
{

    string filename;
    cout<<"Enter output filename: "; //geting filename
    cin>>filename;

    ofstream output; //declaring an output file stream

    output.open(filename.c_str()); // c_str() converts a C++ string into a 
                                  // c-style string (char array) &
                                  //open binds an ofstream to a file

    for(int i=0; i<count; i++)
    {

        output<<A[i].cellnum<<"\t"
              <<A[i].numofrelay<<"\t"
              <<A[i].call_length<<"\t"
              <<A[i].net_cost<<"\t"
              <<A[i].tax_rate<<"\t"
              <<A[i].call_tax<<"\t"
              <<A[i].total_cost<<"\t"
              <<A[i].discount_aval<<endl;

    }

    output.close();
}

int Search(client_db A[], int count, string cellnum)
////Description: Locates cellnumbers in A's fields
{ int index = -1;

for(int i=0; i<count; i++)
{
    if (!(A[i].cellnum.compare(cellnum)))
    {
        cout<<i<<endl;
        index = i;
        break;
    }
}
return index;
}


void Add(client_db A[], int &count)
////Description: Adds key to the array
{
    if (!IsFull(count))
    {
        cout<<"Enter a cellphone number, number of relay stations and the call lenght and if a discount is available: ";
        cin>>A[count].cellnum>>A[count].numofrelay>>A[count].call_length>>A[count].discount_aval;
        count++;

    }
    else
    {
        cout<<"The list is full\n";
    }

}

void Add(client_db A[], int &count, client_db &db)
////Description: Adds key to the array
{
    if (!IsFull(count))
    {
        A[count] = db; 
        count++;

    }
    else
    {
        cout<<"The list is FULL! \n";
    }

}
void Remove(client_db A[], int *count, string cellnum )

////Description: Removes the number from the array is it is there
{
int loc;
while((loc=Search(A,*count,cellnum)) != -1)
{
      if (IsEmpty(*count)){
          cout<<"There is nothing to remove\n";
          return;
      }
      else if (loc == -1){
          cout<<"Number is not in data\n";
      }
      else
      {
          for(int j=loc; j<(*count)-1; j++)
          {
              A[j] = A[j+1];
          }
          (*count)--;

      }
}
}

void Call_stats(client_db A[],int count) // prints to screen
{

    for(int i=0; i<count; i++)
    {
        cout<<A[i].cellnum<<"\t"
            <<A[i].numofrelay<<"\t"
            <<A[i].call_length<<"\t"
            <<A[i].discount_aval<<endl;

    }
}
void Menu ()
{
    cout<<"The values of the filename you entered have been recognized"<<endl;
    cout<<"Please enter the letter of your application of choice"<<endl;
    cout<<"       "<<endl;
    cout<<"************  WELCOME TO THE MAIN MENU  ************"<<endl;
    cout<<" Add an item...........................A"<<endl;
    cout<<" Remove an item........................R"<<endl;
    cout<<" Search for an item....................S"<<endl;
    cout<<" Print current data....................P"<<endl;
    cout<<" Print to output file..................O"<<endl;
    cout<<" List Discount info....................D"<<endl;
    cout<<"****************************************************"<<endl;
}

void Discount ( client_db A[], int count, string discount)
{
    cout<<"Enter 'yes' for discounts and 'no' for no discounts:  "<<endl;
    cin>>discount;

    for(int i=0; i<count; i++)
{
    if (!(A[i].discount_aval.compare(discount)))
    {

        cout <<A[i].cellnum<<"\t"
              <<A[i].numofrelay<<"\t"
              <<A[i].call_length<<"\t"
              <<A[i].net_cost<<"\t"
              <<A[i].tax_rate<<"\t"
              <<A[i].call_tax<<"\t"
              <<A[i].total_cost<<"\t"
              <<A[i].discount_aval<<endl;

    }
    }
}





int main()
{

    char answer;
    char answer2;
    string discount;
    client_db CLIENT[CAPACITY]; //declaring database
    int count = 0;   //initializing count
    string cellnum;

    string filename;
    cout<<"Hello!, this program holds clients call data records."<<endl;
    cout<<"Enter input filename: "; //geting filename
    cin>>filename;

    ifstream input; //declaring an input file stream

    input.open(filename.c_str()); // c_str() converts a C++ string into
        while(count<CAPACITY && !input.eof()) //reading until the end of the file (eof=end-of-file)
    {


        input>>CLIENT[count].cellnum
        >>CLIENT[count].numofrelay
        >>CLIENT[count].call_length
        >>CLIENT[count].discount_aval;

        count++;

    }

    do
{

  Menu();
  cout<<"Please enter a command letter:  "<<endl;
    cin>>answer;
    client_db db;

    switch (answer)
{

case 'A' : 
    cout<<"Enter a cellphone number, number of relay stations and the call lenght and if a discount is available: "<<endl;
    cin>>db.cellnum>>db.numofrelay>>db.call_length>>db.discount_aval;
    Add(CLIENT, count, db);
break;
case 'R' : cout<<"Please enter a phone number:   "<<endl;
cin>>cellnum;
Remove(CLIENT,&count,cellnum); 

break;
case 'S' : 
    cout<<"Please enter a phone number:   "<<endl;
    cin>>cellnum;
    Search(CLIENT,count,cellnum); 

break;
case 'P' : Call_stats(CLIENT,count);
break;
case 'O' :
    Process(CLIENT,count); //how do i set the precision for this?
    Print_DB(CLIENT,count);
break;
case 'D':
    Process(CLIENT,count); 
    Discount(CLIENT,count,discount);
    }
     cout<<"Would you like to make another command?(y/n):   "<<endl;
   cin>>answer2;
} while (answer2 == 'Y' || answer2 == 'y');
 cout<<"Goodbye"<<endl;
    return 0;






}
```

Comment: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iomanip/setprecision/ sets the decimal precision to be used by output operations.

Answer (score 1):

you should use `iomanip` header for this.

use `setw(width)` to set the width of output : `cout<<setw(5)<<"Hello"`

here are more functions you can look [IOMANIP](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iomanip/) (Take a look).

Similer to this :

```
output<<setw(10)<<A[i].cellnum<<"\t"
              <<setw(4)<<A[i].numofrelay<<"\t"
              <<setw(4)<<A[i].call_length<<"\t"
              <<setw(6)<<A[i].net_cost<<"\t"
              <<setw(5)<<A[i].tax_rate<<"\t"
              <<setw(6)<<A[i].call_tax<<"\t"
              <<setw(7)<<A[i].total_cost<<"\t"
              <<setw(4)<<A[i].discount_aval<<endl;
```

Answer (score 0):

Similar to cout, an output file can be manipulated just the same. Use `<iomanip>` with your output file:

```
output << fixed << showpoint << setprecision(2);
```

formatting output:

```
const int TAB = 12;
output << right << num1 << setw(TAB) << num2 << setw(TAB) << num3 << endl;
//and so on..
```

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iomanip/

EDIT: About your file reading loop, it won't give you the results you expect. Here is a correct way to write a file loop:

```
ifstream inFile("in.txt");
int value; //value infile will read into
//read once BEFORE the loop starts
inFile >> value;

while (inFile && count<CAPACITY) {
//manipulate/handle the input above
inFile >> value; //read in the next value
}
```

Comment: I tried that right after i opened the file but now i get really huge numbers for the first set of values in the array. like huge!